# AWS 3-Tier Architecture Issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, devops, system-design

Need some serious help here, thanks a lot in advance !

I need to deploy a scalable 3 tier web application on AWS and I am having some doubts/trouble understanding the best practice to design the architecture.

NOTE: *As per my understanding, all the backend requests are requested through the browser, after the Frontend server serves html/css/js to the user.*

Let me show you  what I have come up with till now :

---

1. *Assuming the above 'note'*:

[image]

Cons (as per my understanding):

- All the backend routes will be exposed to the outside world.
- Even though backend servers are in private subnet, now that they're being accessed via external load balancer, the endpoints API could be accessed from the users.
- How will we route a request from a Load balancer to another Load balancer. Because what I have seen is that you could only route a request to an EC2 instance added in the target group.

---

2. *To overcome the cons as I think in the above approach, I came up with this architecture instead:*

[image]

Pros (as per my understanding):

- The backend routes are safe (in a way) because we have a way of internally connecting from the frontend to the backend servers(if required).

Cons:

- If the request is made from the browser, the endpoints are again exposed.

---

3. *Solution that I found online*:

[image]

```
REAL BIG DOUBT IN THIS LAST ONE
```

This breaks all the logic of my understanding that : *All the requests are made by the browser from the user to the backend* because in this the requests to the backend are being routed FROM the frontend servers.

---

**QUESTIONS**

> What if the backend request (say login) is made by the user from the browser?

> How will this work out in such case?

Comment: Are you saying that users from the Internet **should not** be allowed to call the `/api`? Should all of their requests go via the front-end servers? Or are they allowed to directly call the `/api`? How will the frontend servers authenticate user requests? They don't seem to be connected to the database? Or is their purpose simply to translate a front-end web application into API calls for the backend, without consulting the database?

Comment: Hi,

I DO NOT want the users to directly access the /api in any case. Because it would mean, <domain_name>/api would show the users the JSON data.
So Can I use the FIRST design for this? Because all the requests are requested VIA the browser(both for frontend and backend). 

Another question: How come there are solutions on internet which say Design #3 is correct(even on some AWS forums), because it clearly destroys the logic of the requests coming from the client side (users broswer) and obviously as we cannot route backend requests "through the frontend servers".

Answer (score 1):

seems like you have done some good work here.

Let me start by making things easy for you:

1. **Users only interact with the Load Balancer**: If you want to keep it simple and not break off your frontend asset serving to an external service like [CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/), which you should if you are starting out, you will be hosting the application only via EC2 instances (application origin, or simply orgin). Your requests would look something like this: 
   Users <--> ALB <--> EC2 
   Notice how **users never interact with EC2 instances directly**, its always via Application Load Balancer (ALB). 
   If I can oversimply thing, this is how HTTP operates, a request is made to a resource at an IP and the response is sent back from the same resource or IP. So as in your diagram, a request will not be responded back by EC2 but rather be relayed via the ALB.
2. **You don't need NAT gateway**: NAT gateway are there to make it possible for resources in provate subnet access the internet. In this case, unless you want your application to access the internet, you don't need NAT gateway. Many large scale applications are actually locked down in part by not keeping this resource at all.
3. **You are still protecting the origin**: Given that only the ALB can be accessed over the internet and everything else internal you can structure things here in any way that you want to. you could have few internal microservices that can be used internally without ever being exposed to end users. Note that here request never leaves the VPN.

You can read more about this and build a sample application via the official docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/application-load-balancer-getting-started.html) or access AWS tutorials [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/application-load-balancer-tutorials.html).

Comment: Thanks lot for going through such a long query and providing a brief explaination.
I still have some doubts: 

1 >>> What I have understood from your answer is that the first diagram would work fine. Does that mean in the first diagram, the user WONT have access to the backend API if accessed like  "<alb_ip>/api "?
2 >>> I am using NATS for some other patching purposes.
3 >>> How come the third diagram seems to be correct solution found on the internet because 'All the requests are made by the browser from the user to  ALB to the backend'.

Comment: To be preceise, there will be no arrow between the backend and user. The user makes a request to the ALB, ALB unpacks it and makes a request to the origin server, when it receives a response, it is used to repond back to the request made by the user. So conceptually yes, EC2 responds to the user, but in terms of how HTTP connections are made, user and server are never directly connected.

Comment: So the first 1st diagram would work just fine?
Another question following the first diagram then, we would need an internal load balancer for a common point of communication for "frontend EC2s -> Backend EC2s (internally)".
Thus, my doubt, how can we route the request from one load balancer to another?

Comment: Ideally you could just route the request from the load balancer to the final destination. You can create multiple target groups and make use of ALB rules and security group to acheive the lockdown you need.

Comment: @KaranKumar, if the answer did indeed address your question, do you mind accepting it. That way, others who stumble upon this can easily find the solution. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

To me, #3 is the correct solution because it does not expose `/api` to end users (since you mention *"I DO NOT want the users to directly access the /api"*). In #1, I don't think you could limit access to `/api` to only the front-end servers, since security groups work on the *whole* load balancer, not per-target.

Also, being an Internet-facing load balancer, any requests from the front-end servers to the load balancer in #1 will be referencing the load balancer via public IP addresses. This will cause a 1c/GB charge to go "out of" the VPC and then back in again.

Only #3 correctly refers to back-end resources via private IP addresses. The internal load balancer will be referenced via private IP addresses.

Comment: Understood, but the #3, doesn't it kill all the logic that 'all the requests to the backend api is made through the client's web browser (since the frontend servers serve html/js code to the user's browser)'.
WHICH MEANS, the request should go from the browser --> externalLoadbalancer --> backend API. Considering this, how would the routing in #3 work? I mean, frontend servers do not have reverse proxy configured in them, they cannot route the requests to the backend, can they?

Comment: But you said _"I DO NOT want the users to directly access the /api"_. Therefore, they would need to access the front-end servers. Are you saying that you _are_ okay with users going to `/api` to the back-end servers without passing through the front-end servers? I'm confused.

Comment: How can we route the requests VIA frontend servers? Their only job is to serve html+css+js to the client's broswser.

Comment: So are you saying that you are okay with `/api` requests being directed to the back-end server? If so, then I would go with #2, with a small change that requests to `/api` are directed to the Internet Load Balancer, so that all requests to back-end servers go through that load balancer. That is, the request would go through two load balancers. The first acts as a 'firewall', the second does the load distribution. Otherwise, there would be two load balancers performing health checks on each back-end instance and distributing load independent of each other.